# js string nesting

Tags: javascript, string, escaping

ok i have a string.

```
"<div class='down_arrow left_side'></div><div class='holder clearfix'><div class='topimg' style='background-image: url("+topimg+");'></div></div>";
```

and i need it to be like this

```
"<div class='down_arrow left_side'></div><div class='holder clearfix'><div class='topimg' style='background-image: url(' "+topimg+" ' );'></div></div>";
```

but the extra ' will close the style tag.

So how do you get past this?... Ive read a few posts like use \ before the quotes but it doesn't really work.

just for some people

```
var friinfo = document.createElement("DIV");
                friinfo.id = "friendsinfo";
                friinfo.className = "friendsinfo";      
                friinfo.innerHTML = "<div class='down_arrow left_side'></div><div class='holder clearfix'><div class='topimg' style='background-image: url(\"+topimg+\");'></div></div>";
                document.body.appendChild(friinfo);
```

This is the actual code

so Just to enforce the question, I want to get a extra layer of quotes in my string below

```
"<div class='down_arrow left_side'></div><div class='holder clearfix'><div class='topimg' style='background-image: url("+topimg+");'></div></div>";
```

so it will turn out to be this

```
"<div class='down_arrow left_side'></div><div class='holder clearfix'><div class='topimg' style='background-image: url(' "+topimg+" ' );'></div></div>";
```

with the quotes '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"<div class=\"down_arrow left_side\"></div><div class=\"holder clearfix\"><div class=\"topimg\" style=\"background-image: url('" + topimg + "');\"></div></div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified Code:

```
"<div class='down_arrow left_side'></div>    <div class='holder clearfix'><div class='topimg' style='background-image: url(\'"+topimg+"\' );'></div></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes with \ in JavaScript but not in HTML. The pure-HTML solution is called HTML entities:

```
<div class='topimg' style='background-image: url(&quot;blah&quot);'>
```

... though it's normally easier to use the fact that there're two quote styles to choose from for your <del>JavaScript</del> CSS needs:

```
<div class="topimg" style="background-image: url('blah');">
```

However, quotes aren't your only issue if you want to inject random text into an HTML attribute. You'd better use the [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute) method and let it take care of escaping.